# Auto Deploy with IIS User from Remote Computer

Tags: iis, microsoft-web-deploy

I've set up Web Deploy on a destination server, and I can verify this because I've created a Publish Profile in Visual Studio, and it validates/works when I use my credentials. Now I want to set it up with an IIS Manager User so I can share those credentials instead of managing multiple accounts. I created an IIS Manager User, gave it access to the site I publish, and try to verify the Publish Profile still works. It fails.

> Connected to 'srvr' using the Web Deployment Agent Service, but could not authorize. Make sure you are an administrator on 'srvr'. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_USER_NOT_ADMIN.
>
> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Looking at the Security logs in Server Manager I can see that it tried (and failed) to validate the IIS Manager User as an account.

Why is `srvr` looking for an account for the IIS Manager User? How can I set it up to use another account? Do I need to do something special under Management Service Delegation? If so, what? (All the instructions I've found seem to set up what I've already got despite claims of including how to set up non-admins or IIS Manager Users.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Web Deploy Agent Service requires administrator access. Try updating your target machine to `https://svr:8172/msdeploy.axd` to use the Web Management Service handler. For more information on the various deployment methods, take a look at [my blog post](https://blog.richardszalay.com/2013/02/02/building-a-deployment-pipeline-with-msdeploy-part-4-server-configuration/) or the [Microsoft documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461175(v=ws.10).aspx).

Keep in mind that if you are using an *IIS* user, you'll need to make sure you've configured delegation rules such that the `contentPath` provider will be able to write to the website's directory with the correct permissions.

To be honest, I'd recommend creating a local Windows user and configuring it for non-administrator deployments. There's documentation on how to do so here: [Configuring a Site for Delegated Non-Administrator Deployment](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later#00)